# Passing Current longitude & latitude on buttonclick event

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

Hello I am using CoreLocation to get latitude and longitude in my map application to get latitude and longitude by using following method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [super viewDidLoad];
   }
```

The _ (void)locationManager.... method is not getting call

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
int minutes = decimal * 60;
double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                 degrees, minutes, seconds];

degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
minutes = decimal * 60;
seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];

   }
```

I want to call lati & longi on Button click event to URL. But it is not working. it passes 0000.0 lati & longi to my url. Can some one tell me how to rectify this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have did this to pass latitude and longitude in to web service URL on button click...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {

    if((fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) > 0.001) ||    (fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) > 0.001)) {
    NSLog(@"Got location %f,%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude,   newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [currentLocation release];
    }
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    [currentLocation retain];
}}
```

and On click event code I have just pass locationmanager.location.coordinate.latitude.....

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.....Url..../hespdirectory/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=%f&lng=%f&radius=%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude,radius];
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any obvious problem with your init of CLLocationManager.  If you are not getting callbacks perhaps it doesn't *yet* have a location available.  You should also implement the error callback and see if it is getting called instead.

I suggest you try one of the [CLLocationManager examples provided by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and see if you can get the example to run.

Answer (score 1):

U can directly change the CLLocation to NSString

```
NSString *lat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.latitude];
NSString *lon=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.longitude];
```

Comment: The above code I have pasted in my Button click event to pass coordinates in URL .....it showing me newLocation undeclare

Comment: You don get the newLocation here.U add this inside of 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
method.And declare lat and lon as global and use them

Comment: my .....(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation is not getting called. I checked by setting breakpoint. what should I do

Comment: R u checking in simulator.If so it will not called.These delegates called oly device

Comment: Right on device the method getting called. Now what should I writ code on button click event to pass lati in url .....I gave NSString * lati = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude]autorelease];    it throwing EXC_BAD_AcCess

Comment: still getting lati = 0.0000 with EXC bad access. Can I mail you my code. I am really stuck here. I am following http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application tutorial for my Map app.  But not getting result

Answer (score 0):

The answers don't show it directly, but you should have assigned your controller as the CLLocationManagerDelegate to recieve the callbacks correct?